# Firebase: How to get elements of the specific collection?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the following data and I want to know, how can I get `brainstormWords` easily?

[image]

Now I'm using this

```kotlin
FirebaseDatabse.getInstance().getReference("Users")
    .child(mUser.uid).addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {

    override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        val brainstormWords = arrayListOf<Pack>()
        for (data in snapshot.children) {
            if (snapshot.key == "brainstormWords") {
                val word = data.getValue(Pack::class.java)!!
                if (word.word.isNotEmpty()) {
                    brainstormWords.add(word)
                }
            }
        }
        if (brainstormWords.isNotEmpty()) {
            trainingPack.postValue(brainstormWords)
        }
    }
}
```

but If there are many collections that will dynamically change, it will not be very convenient. Maybe I can somehow get all the data from `brainstormWords` by simply specifying the path to the collection?

Comment: Yes, specifying the full path is the typical way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase always loads complete nodes. There's no way to load just the `brainstormWords` child of each node. If you want to load just those, the best practice is to create a top-level list `brainstormWords` with the same child nodes you now have, but then with only contents of each `brainstormWords` child.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [avoiding nested data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) and [flattening data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#flatten_data_structures).

---

As a separate note: in your current node you don't need to loop over all children to find `brainstormWords`. You can instead use `DataSnapshot.child()`:

```
FirebaseDatabse.getInstance().getReference("Users")
    .child(mUser.uid).addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {

    override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        val brainstormWords = arrayListOf<Pack>()
        val word = data.child("brainstormWords").getValue(Pack::class.java)!!
        if (word.word.isNotEmpty()) {
            brainstormWords.add(word)
        }
        if (brainstormWords.isNotEmpty()) {
            trainingPack.postValue(brainstormWords)
        }
    }
}
```